# Ephemeral replies in Discord.js v14 slash commands not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

User
I am currently developing a Discord.js 14.14 bot, focusing on Slash Commands and interactions. I've run into an issue concerning the behavior of ephemeral messages, specifically in scenarios that involve deferred replies and subsequent follow-up messages.

In my code, the artistsEmbed and albumsEmbed replies in my code **should not be ephemeral**. However, when the user is attempting to fetch an undefined or non-existent user (resulting in a 404 error), the responses to that **should be ephemeral**.
Unfortunately, setting ephemeral to true or false appears to have no effect, or at least, it is not functioning as I would expect.

I have set `interaction.deferReply();` at the beginning of the interaction execution, to avoid timeouts as the functions may take longer to execute.

Here is the problematic part of my code:

```
try {
    // ... functions irrelevant to my problem
    await interaction.editReply({
      embeds: [artistsEmbed],
      ephemeral: false,
    });
    await interaction.followUp({
      embeds: [albumsEmbed],
      ephemeral: false,
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error.message);

    let responseContent;

    if (error.isAxiosError && error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
      const notFoundUser = error.config.url.split("user=")\[1\].split("&")\[0\];
      responseContent = `User ${notFoundUser} not found.`;
    } else {
      responseContent = "Error occurred. Please try again later.";
    }

    await interaction.editReply({
      content: responseContent,
      ephemeral: true,
    });

// debug
    await interaction.followUp({
      content: "Test follow-up, should be ephemeral.",
      ephemeral: true,
    });
}
```

With my approach, the error reply is sent as a non-ephemeral reply, which would be incorrect. However, the debugging follow-up I added is ephemeral.

If I set deferring to `interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });` at the top, error messages will be sent as ephemeral, which would be correct.
But then the first regular response will also be ephemeral, even though it is set to ephemeral: false. In this case, the first regular response is the [artistsEmbed] one.

I am wondering if my approach of deferring the reply at the very top of the execution is incorrect. Should I somehow separately define it for cases with errors (`deferReply({ ephemeral: true })`) and cases without issues (`deferReply({ ephemeral: false })`)? But I'm not sure how I would do that yet and I'm hoping there's a better approach allowing to set ephemeral state separately for each reply/followup.

I'm a bit lost and would appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options passed into `interaction.editReply` method, unlike for `interaction.followUp`, do not accept an `ephemeral` property, as you can see [here](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/CommandInteraction:Class#editReply), so setting this property on an `editReply` has no effect whatsoever.

This is how I would handle it:

- I would defer the received interaction with the `ephemeral` property set to `true`.
- If the request was successfully resolved, I would edit the received interaction with a message that represented a successful response, and then `followUp` on it with the `ephemeral` property set to `false`, containing the actual relevant data. **Note that you must first `editReply` on the original received interaction before you `followUp`.**
- If the request was *not* successfully resolved, I would just `editReply` the original received interaction.

```
        try {
            // First defer the received interaction as an ephemeral.
            await interaction.deferReply({
                ephemeral: true,
            });

            // (Processing)

            // If we made it here, it means the request was successfully resolved.
            await interaction.editReply({
                embeds: [/* Something representing a successful request. */]
            });

            await interaction.followUp({
                embeds: [artistsEmbed],
                ephemeral: false,
            });

            await interaction.followUp({
                embeds: [albumsEmbed],
                ephemeral: false,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error.message);
    
            let responseContent;
    
            if (error.isAxiosError && error.response && error.response.status === 404) {
                const notFoundUser = error.config.url.split("user=")\[1\].split("&")\[0\];
                responseContent = `User ${notFoundUser} not found.`;
            } else {
                responseContent = "Error occurred. Please try again later.";
            }
    
            await interaction.editReply({
                content: responseContent,
                // ephemeral: true, // This is removed since it's not doing anything.
            });
        }
```